# get_avatar from user id

Tags: php

1 - I have two members witch settings are set to subscribers.

2 - I have made a page in wordpress with the code:

```
<img src="get_avatar" alt="Logano" onerror="this.src='./files/defaultHead.jpg'">Get_name
```

3. Now I want get the members avatar to that img and also the name to this page.

How do I do this, what do I have to do?

I've tried to find a answer but I only see this: `<?php echo get_avatar( $id1, $size, $default, $alt ); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

To display users with specific ID's on a page you'll need to run a `WP_User_Query`, either by placing the following code in your functions.php and calling it with a shortcode or adding it to the page template:

```
//Replace the numbers 1, 2 with the user ID's to return
$args = array(
    'include' => array( 1, 2 )
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

// User Loop
if ( ! empty( $user_query->results ) ) {
    foreach ( $user_query->results as $user ) {
        echo '<p>' . $user->display_name . '</p>';
        echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 120);
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users found.';
}
```

Comment: Thank you this made something happen on the page! But now it as you wrote, showed out the users! I want to call and get the avatar to a certain ing on the page <img src='<?php echo get_avatar("2") ?>' alt=''>

Comment: Do you have lots of subscriber users but you only want to show two specific ones?  Can you link to the page?

Comment: For now I just have 3 users testing, but there will be many... sorry I'm not aloud to show it for the client I'm trying to help.

Comment: @lamberta I have updated the code and you can put in the user ID's of the specific users you want to return, beyond this you need to develop the code yourself inside the `foreach` loop.